# Facebook like box customize

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I would like to customise the facebook like box, data stream. I want to be able to change text size, font.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your question should be very specific. Do not expect someone to do all the work for you.